# Insertar datos en entidad muchos a muchos C# EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, net

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto pequeño, pero quiero hacer un insert a una tabla intermedia que tiene los datos de muchos a muchos.

Diagrama de Base de Datos
[image: Diagrama de Base de Datps]

Y este es el Diagrama de EntityFramework en Visual Studio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: que código hiciste hasta el momento? que error te arroja?

Comment: Este es el codigo.
context.Productos.Attach(productos.Productos);
                    context.PedidosProductos.Add(productos);
                   
                    context.SaveChanges();

Tambien trate quitando los Attach, y cosas asi, pero no me funciona

Este es el error

System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: 'An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.'
InvalidOperationException: A dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column. Column: 'Id_Producto'.

Comment: @AndreyC1995 Saludos, tengo una duda sobre tu diagrama de Entidad y relación (Base de datos),  según lo que veo en la tabla intermedia "PedidosProductos", no tiene ninguna llave primaria. Te recomiendo colocar como llave primaria (Compuesta), las columnas: **Id_Producto e Id_Pedido**. Posteriormente actualiza tu modelo (Diagrama de EntityFramework en Visual Studio).

Comment: @diego orellana efectivamente eran las llaves primarias que me hacian falta, ya lo probe y funciono perfectamente.

Gracias un Saludos.